# ToolBar above BottomSheetDialog

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, bottom-sheet

How to show a ToolBar above a BottomSheetDialog ? When the dialog is shown, the screen gets a dark tint so the ToolBar seems to be below the dialog and not clickable. How can I my ToolBar (or any other view) "above the dialog" ? Or maybe there is a way to put the dialog below the ToolBar ?

Here is hat I have :
 [image]

And this is what I want (ToolBar above / dialog below) :

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a `BottomSheetDialog` if you don't want it to display as a dialog above the rest of your app? Tapping outside of it closes the dialog by default.

Comment: I want the `BottomSheetDialog ` to display above the app, but I want to let a view visible and clickable. Actually it's not really a toolBar it just has the shape of it. I am currently thinking of an another design but I still want to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

`BottomSheetDialog` specifically dismisses if the user clicks outside of it, hence the overlay of the rest of your Activity. If you'd prefer to keep it open and allow other parts of your UI to be active (rather than move your `Toolbar` shaped view into the `BottomSheetDialog`), you should just attach a [BottomSheetBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html) to a View in your hierarchy.

Comment: I know about BottomSheetBehavior, I use it somewhere else in my app,  but in this particular case  I want to keep to bottomSheetDialog because it acts like a dialog and it does not let the user any other choice than clicking in it or dismiss it.

Comment: Then everything you want to be clickable should be in the dialog.

Comment: No, the interaction patterns of a `BottomSheetDialog` seem incompatible with your design.